# How can I close a buffer in VIM without making it 'unlisted'?

Tags: vim, macvim

If I close a buffer in VIM with `:bd` and then later on decide to open the same file again.. it will not be listed in the contents of the `:ls` command because it is marked as unlisted.  Is there anyway to close a buffer such that if I do decide to reopen it later it is still available in the buffer list via `:ls`?

I understand I can see it in the 'hidden' list with `:ls!` but that isn't what I'm looking for here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I really want to get rid of a buffer, I do `:bw`. Usually, I simply do `:q`.

Comment: bw allows me to close it but reopen it and see it in LS which is what I was asking.. thank yo

Comment: No. `:bw` deletes everything related to a buffer: you can't see it in the output of `:ls` or `:ls!`. If the buffer is displayed in a split window, `:q` is enough to make the buffer (and the window) go away but stay reachable. If you only have one main window and multiple hidden buffers you are not supposed to "close" a buffer: you are supposed to open another one in the same window.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:ls!` to see it.

Instead, `:bw` is the right way to *wipe* the buffer, so that it will never be listed any more.

This **IS** what `:bd` and `:ls` mean to do. Accept it.

On the other hand, if you have multiple windows, what you need may be `^Wc` or `:clo`, which close the current window so that the buffer is not displayed while still being listed.